# Laravel 8: how to set ID in session

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-8

I am trying to set ID in my businesses table as business_id in session

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#388 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1265 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"user_id": 1
      +"business_name": "my company"
      +"type_of_business": "Financial Services"
      +"country": "Canada"
      +"business_currency": "USD"
      +"type_of_organization": "Partnership"
      +"is_personal": 1
      +"created_at": "2021-02-05 02:18:33"
      +"updated_at": "2021-02-09 10:52:34"
      +"is_deleted": 0
      +"deleted_at": null
    }
  ]
}
```

for example, I want to set the "id" as "business_id" in my session

Comment: You can use session helper to set a session value e.g. session('business_id', $collection->first()->id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store this collection in a variable, let's assume you saved it as `$business`.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#388 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1265 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"user_id": 1
      +"business_name": "my company"
      +"type_of_business": "Financial Services"
      +"country": "Canada"
      +"business_currency": "USD"
      +"type_of_organization": "Partnership"
      +"is_personal": 1
      +"created_at": "2021-02-05 02:18:33"
      +"updated_at": "2021-02-09 10:52:34"
      +"is_deleted": 0
      +"deleted_at": null
    }
  ]
}

\Session::set('business_id', $business->id); //this line of code is to store id as 
                                             //session
```

To get the variable, you'd use...

```
\Session::get('business_id');
```

Hope this will be useful.